# SVG drag memory leak

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've implemented a simple draggable rectangle using raphael.js:

```
var paper = Raphael('container', '100%', '100%');
var elements = paper.rect(10, 20, 300, 200).attr({ fill: "#FC0" });
var o_x, o_y;
elements.drag(function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {
    elements.translate(x - o_x, y - o_y);
    o_x = x;
    o_y = y;
}, 
function (x, y, e) {
    o_x = x;
    o_y = y;
},
function (e) { });
```

With the following html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

After dragging the rectangle and shaking a lot for about 20 seconds, memory usage shoots up 200mb, and dragging becomes very unresponsive. What's the problem with my code? I've tested this on firefox 22.

Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jyhAx/

`.transform()` however appears to work without memory leaks.

Comment: Same thing happens in Chrome (it doesn't actually drop off, the graph just looks like that for some reason): http://i.imgur.com/tqtZhEB.png

Comment: maybe that's why translate is deprecated and the docs say to use transform.